# Popover with MGSplitViewController inside - Orientation Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I was searching for a way how to get a SplitViewController inside a PopoverController.
([Popover with Splitview inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710550/popover-with-splitview-inside))

Now i got this work with using the MGSplitViewController, but i have so,e Problems with the Layout depending on the Orientation.

**1.** When i set

```
showsMasterInPortrait = YES;
```

It's look like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd31R.png

**2.** When i set

```
showsMasterInLandscape = YES;
```

It's look like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWCSp.png

My target is to have a SplitView with Master | Detail Sections (like in case 1) where the Detail stretches it's content to the same width as the width of popover-controller.

Here is my Code:

```
MGSplitViewController *customSplitVC = [[MGSplitViewController alloc] init];

customSplitVC.showsMasterInPortrait = YES;
customSplitVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[customSplitVC setSplitPosition:400 animated:YES];

DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
detailViewController.title = @"Detail";

ListViewController *listViewController = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithDetailViewController:detailViewController];
listViewController.title = @"Master";
listViewController.content = self.myContent;

UINavigationController *detaillNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

listViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

UINavigationController *masterNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:listViewController];
customSplitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNC, detaillNC, nil];
customSplitVC.delegate = detailViewController;

UINavigationController *customSplitNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:customSplitVC];

UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"X" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissPopover)];
customSplitVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnCancel;

self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:customSplitNC];
self.popover.delegate = self;
self.popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 500);

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 1, 1);

[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:NO];
```

Thanks for your Help

Comment: If anyone is thinking to use MGSplitViewController, or has already used it and can still change, then I advise you not to use it. I have worked on a project that uses it and I must say that it is a mess. The way the whole thing is set up is amateurish (we all pass through such a point don't we.) For example rotation messages are manually passed to the master and detail view controllers. If they had been added as child view controllers of their container controller then this would happen automatically. This is just an example among many other flaws with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:[UINavigationController issue in the master view (iOS 6)](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/issues/69)

The easiest way I've found that works is to add the following to MGSplitViewController.m at the end of -(void)setup

self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;

Comment: thx for your reply but it does not work for me (iOS7). what kind of orientation do you use your MGSplitViewController ?

Comment: add `[self layoutSubviewsForInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation withAnimation:YES];` to `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`,it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `MGSplitViewController` instance is added as the `rootViewController` of the `window`.